# Sqlite database corrupted, but integrity_check passes

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database running version 3.6.18 that is returning a corruption error when executing a select statement. There seems to be a single corrupt row.

```
sqlite> select * from modb;
.
.
.
SQL error: database disk image is malformed
sqlite> select * from modb where KEY=149;
SQL error: database disk image is malformed
```

But when i run a pragma integrity check on the same database it returns 'ok'

```
sqlite> pragma integrity_check;
ok
```

What kind of corruption does an integrity_check not catch? Or what could cause a single row to get corrupted, while the overall health of the database seems to be ok?

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for this?